# addSubViewをすると2本指ドラッグが検出されなくなる

Tags: swift

以下のコードで、1本指ドラッグと2本指ドラッグを実装しました。
以下のコードでは、2本指ドラッグが検出されません。ただし、1本指ドラッグは検出されます。

そして、`self.view.addSubview(firstView)`の行をコメントアウトすると、2本指ドラッグも検出されるようになります。

```
import UIKit
import Foundation


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var firstView: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(firstView)
        self.view.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
    }
    
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
    {
        // タッチイベントを取得
        let touchEvent = touches.first!
        
        //指の本数
        let fingerNum = touches.count
        
        if fingerNum == 1
        {
            print("1本指ドラッグ")
        }
        else if fingerNum == 2
        {
            print("2本指ドラッグ")
        }
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

単純に、`self.view.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true`の行を、`self.firstView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true`に書き換えれば、addSubViewをした後でも2本指ドラッグが検出されます。

しかし、今回はそれをやらずに`self.view.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true`のままで2本指ドラッグを実装したいと考えています。

なぜ、addSubViewをすると1本指ドラッグは検出されるのに、2本指ドラッグだけ検出されなくなるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 単純に、self.view.isMultipleTouchEnabled = trueの行を、self.firstView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = trueに書き換えれば、addSubViewをした後でも2本指ドラッグが検出されます。
> しかし、今回はそれをやらずにself.view.isMultipleTouchEnabled = trueのままで2本指ドラッグを実装したいと考えています。

UIView の isUserInteractionEnabled プロパティはデフォルト true です。
self.firstView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
とすれば
self.view.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
としているので
self.view で2本指ドラッグを検出できます。

> なぜ、addSubViewをすると1本指ドラッグは検出されるのに、2本指ドラッグだけ検出されなくなるのでしょうか？

self.view.addSubview(firstView) により self.view の上に配置された self.firstView の isMultipleTouchEnabled が false のため2本指ドラッグが検出できなくなってますね。